# How are angels categorized in Judaism?

Tags: malach-angel, soul

Are they Neshamot or are they something else? Because if they are Neshamot they would be like us, so what forms a angel are they like Only Yetzer Hatov so they only have the desire to do God's will?

Comment: here is one summary http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/692875/jewish/What-Are-Angels.htm

Comment: Some angels can make 'mistakes'.

Comment: Rambam has an interesting view regarding angels. Something in which I shall not describe here.

Answer (score 1):

Derech Hashem 1:5:1

> הרוחניים, הם נבראים משוללים מגשם, בלתי מורגשים מחושינו, ומתחלקים לשני מינים, האחד נשמות, והשני נבדלים. הנשמות, הם מין נבראים רוחניים, התעתדו לבא בתוך גוף, ליגבל בתוכו וליקשר בו בקשר אמיץ, ולפעול בו פעולות שונות בזמנים שונים. הנבדלים, הם מין נבראים רוחניים, בלתי מעותדים לגופות כלל, ונחלקים לשני חלקים, הא' נקרא כחות, והב' מלאכים.
>
> Spiritual entities, which are creations removed from any physicality and undetectable by our senses, are divided into two categories.  The first is *neshamos*, and the second are transcendentals.  The *neshamos* are a type of spiritual creation which are destined to be put into a body, to be bound in it and connected to it, and to act through it.  The transcendentals are spiritual beings which are not destined to go into bodies, and they are divided into two sections, the first are called "forces" and the second are angels.

So no, angels are not *Neshamos*. They are purely spiritual beings which have no connection to physicality.

Comment: I dont have this sefer. Please carry on what are 'forces' and what are 'angels'.

Comment: @cham what do you mean by "I don't have this sefer"?

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv I think it’s pretty self-explanatory. The OP quotes a Sefer which he doesn’t have.